# Haar measure on the positive real numbers

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, haar-measure

Consider the locally compact Hausdorff topological group $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, I can use Haar theorem to show that there is a Haar measure on my borel sets. However, I am having trouble determining it. I noticed that $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, which I can use the lebesgue measure. However, I am having troublee constructing a measure $m$ such that $m(Ex) = m(E)$ for $E$ being a borel set, which satisfies the Haar measure properties.

Comment: Think about $(0,1)$ and $(0,x)$. Set up the measure of these sets as integrals of characteristic functions supported on these intervals with respect to an unknown measure. Then do a change of variable and see what this tells you about the measure. From there, you'll want to show that this is actually the Haar measure on the space.

Comment: The inclusion of positive reals with multiplication into all reals with addition is not playing well with the operations on both sides. Do you have some other function instead of inclusion between the same things but does play well with the operations?

Comment: Ah yes good point I forgot to mention ^. The reals are pretty special as LCA groups go because they are also an ordered field, so they have a bit more going on than most LCA groups. Don't mix up the two group operations like this.

Comment: One way to identify Haar measure on a group is to find an isomorphism to a group whose Haar measure you already know. Is $(\Bbb R_{>0},\times)$ isomorphic to another group whose Haar measure you know? What is the isomorphism?